Why do I fail to import the SVG file from this site?
Importing vector data from another source can be very useful for 3D printing. e.g. import some writings to engrave a surface, etc.
In this case, I've been trying to import a David Smith's tiling background image in openSCAD, but it failed miserably and I have no idea about why it fails.
Here is what I did:

I went to Craig S. Kaplan's page about David Smith's tiling.



Then I clicked on the [Save SVG] button, and saved the file on my computer.

Then I tried to import it in openSCAD with the following code:


    resize([200, 100, 10]) 
        linear_extrude(10)
            import("C:/Users/phil/Downloads/David Smith Single Tile.svg");

and... Nothing happens.

Then, I tried to render instead of preview, and I got in the log the following notice:


"WARNING: No top level geometry to render"

I have no idea of the specificities of SVG files nor what could happen or how to address this problem. Please help...

How does this relate to 3D printing?

Of course, @Velvet : When you save a file, you can change this name

What do you think I will be doing with this tile, @Agarza ? But you are right : I forgot that last time I asked an openSCAD question, I asked it on Stackoverflow and not here

FWIW, I managed to import this SVG into Fusion, so the model seems to be fine: https://i.sstatic.net/6H09ySpB.png. But you have to take note that the tile was imported far from the origin (https://i.sstatic.net/VgC4jnth.png). Maybe that could be the issue... (e.g. restricted drawing environment?)

I had no doubt on the fact that the SVG file was OK. I suspect it has some characteristics that make it not understandable by OpenSCAD, but I have no idea about what it could be and how to address the problem. By the way, I took the simplest example I could find, but in fact, what I would like to import, is the level twice above, when one have generated super tiles, but I wanted to start with an easy example.

Your question has been flagged to be closed for not being on-topic (not by me). I suggest you [edit] the question so this does not happen.

You might open it in Blender do your editing in blender and export as STL
Or dont edit in blender and directly export to STL or OBJ or some format your drawing tool requires. SVG's can be different there are a few version standards of them, from what i've noted is that blender is okay with opening them.

Even though it might seem obvious, as previously requested, please [edit] and specify that you will be printing the file -
then it can be voted to be left open (it is one vote away from being closed). Also, please keep all additional info in the question, rather than in the comments. Thanks.

Frankly, 3D modeling is a major side of 3D printing and I don't know of a better space than this one to ask for this question. Specifying that I'm going to print the project is not relevant to understand the question and will just add noise to it. If people want to suppress knowledge to satisfy their ego, it just shows who they are and I'm not even surprised. Feel free to do it. I got the answer I needed.

Many 3D models are not intended to be printed, in fact I would hazard a guess that only a small percentage of 3D designs are intended to be printed. Please understand that if we don't request that OP's specify that the object is for printing, then we will open up ourselves to many many 3D design questions. We have had this issue before, and have managed to contain it. It is nothing about egos, it is simply a question of what was deemed as [on-topic] during the beta stage. We set a (very) low bar of just requiring a simple statement in the question such as "I intend to print the model".

... it isn't much to ask for, really, and doesn't really contribute to "noise". Nevertheless, thank you for posting a solution which will hopefully help others. You might find this useful, Where can questions that are purely about 3D modelling, or CAD, software be asked?. There's also a meta question regarding why (purely) 3D design questions are off-topic, but I can't find the link at the moment.

I have read your link with attention, and I believe you have problem with defining the limit criterion. It is completely irrelevant if I will print it or not. The right question should rather be : is this useful for 3D printing which is quite different. I can rephrase my post in this context.

OK, Problem solved :
It appears that both the viewBox attribute in the <SVG ...> tag and  and  tags are unsupported by openScad. So I solved the problem by just removing both the viewBox attribute in the SVG tag and defs tags as mentioned  with a text editor, and then I cleaned the file with inkscape.
